# MySQL same column join with different rows

Tags: mysql

I have two tables related to projects as following

Table, "old_project"

```
+------------+----------+--------------+----------+
| project_no | project  |    amount    |  status  |
+------------+----------+--------------+----------+
|        001 | project1 |   75,000.00  | original |
|        002 | project2 |   32,000.00  | original |
|        003 | project3 |  150,000.00  | original |
|        004 | project4 |   25,000.00  | original |
|        005 | project5 |   45,000.00  | original |
|        006 | project6 |   80,000.00  | original |
+------------+----------+--------------+----------+
```

Table, "new_project"

```
+----------------+------------+-----------+--------------+----------+
| old_project_no | project_no |  project  |    amount    |  status  |
+----------------+------------+-----------+--------------+----------+
|                |        001 | project1  |   75,000.00  | original |
|                |        002 | project2  |   32,000.00  | original |
|                |        003 | project3  |  150,000.00  | original |
|            001 |        004 | project4  |   50,000.00  | revised  |
|                |        005 | project5  |   45,000.00  | original |
|            003 |        006 | project6  |   70,000.00  | revised  |
+----------------+------------+-----------+--------------+----------+
```

02) If a project has old_project_no and status = "revised" in new_project_table, the amount field should be changed as follows :

eg:-
a) the amount of project_no 004  = the amount of project_no 001 in old_project table - the amount of project_no 004 in new_project table

b) the amount of project_no 006  = the amount of project_no 003 in old_project table - the amount of project_no 006 in new_project table

03) After that the desired output should be as follows by joining two tables :

```
+------------+-----------+--------------+----------+
| project_no |  project  |    amount    |  status  |
+------------+-----------+--------------+----------+
|        001 | project1  |   75,000.00  | original |
|        004 | project4  |   50,000.00  | revised  |
|        003 | project3  |  150,000.00  | original |
|        006 | project6  |   70,000.00  | revised  |
+------------+-----------+--------------+----------+
```

04) So, I used the following query

```
SELECT
    project_no,
    project,
    old_project.amount - new_project.amount,
    status
FROM
    new_project
JOIN
    old_project ON old_project.project.no = new_project.project.no
WHERE
    project_no IN (SELECT project_no
                   FROM new_project
                   WHERE status="revised")
```

05) But did't get the desired output. I an't understand what I am going wrong. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: @Madhur Bhaiya. No it is a simple mistake. Not project10 and project11. It is project4 and project6

Comment: Why dont you have project2 and project5 in your output table ? Also you amount for project4 and project6 dont match with the described calculations

Comment: Fix the desired output, so people don't get confused, the amount goal for project 4 (based on your description) should be `75,000.00 - 50,000.00 = 25,000.00` and not `50,000.00`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You simply need to do a `Left Join` from `new_project` table to the `old_project` table on `project_no`.
- Now, we can use [`Case .. When`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) expressions, to evaluate amount value conditionally.
- If there is a corresponding old project (old project amount [`Is Not Null`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-not-null)), we can calculate the difference; else use the new project amount.

Try the following query:

```
SELECT
  np.project_no, 
  np.project, 
  CASE 
    WHEN op.amount IS NOT NULL THEN op.amount - np.amount 
    ELSE np.amount
  END AS amount, 
  np.status 
FROM new_project AS np 
LEFT JOIN old_project AS op ON op.old_project_no = np.project_no
```

Comment: You are correct. But the amount deduction performing within the old_project table. new_project_table is conceptual

Comment: @MCITTrends You can do "self-join". Replace `new_project` with `old_project` (left join between the same table).

Comment: @MCITTrends also your question does not mention this detail at all, that everything is in the same table.

Comment: You are correct. Are you working as free lance. We have some codeigniter mysql projects to be done. If yes, send me your details to mcodeit@gmail.com